# How do I use a global javascript variable in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs

I have a file variables.js in top src directory, it declares a global variable.

```
declare var the_top;
```

In a component I want to access this variable but it claims it's not declared?

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from "react";
import {the_top} from "../variables";

const TopElement = (props) => {
    const [topElement, setTopElement] = useState();

    the_top = "test";
```

Gives

```
ReferenceError: assignment to undeclared variable the_top
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `variables.js` use `export var the_top` instead.
Then import it using `import { the_top } from './variables'`
Keep in mind that importing a variable makes it read only and therefore, you won't be able to execute `the_top = 'blabla'`

If you want to make your variable properly global, assign it to window instead :
`window.the_top = 'test'` and then print it using `console.log(window.the_top)`

Also, declare is not a thing is JS. Only in typescript to declare a type

Comment: I don't understand this. When I write export var the_top = "bla"; and in the useEffect console.log(the_top); it prints "bla" to the console but when I put the_top = "blabla" I before that console.log, get the reference error again.

Comment: And when I write window.the_top = "blabla" I don't get a reference error but console.log still prints only "bla"

Answer (score 1):

using `export default the_top` , there isn't a need to destructure .
Simply type
`import the_top from '../variables'` (Only 1 default variable can be exported) 
as mentioned above use `window.the_top` for global variable.
Anyways, all the variables need to be exported that are to be used in another file.

Comment: It works with default export, but I need to export more variables in that file. Can't default export multiples